# how can I use vcpkg to install sqlite3 and use in cmakelist.txt?

Tags: c++, sqlite, cmake, vcpkg

I use vcpkg to load sqlite3 for my C++ project.

#### for vcpkg,

I think I integrate it correctly:

```
PS D:\tool\vcpkg\vcpkg> .\vcpkg.exe integrate install
Applied user-wide integration for this vcpkg root.

All MSBuild C++ projects can now #include any installed libraries.
Linking will be handled automatically.
Installing new libraries will make them instantly available.

CMake projects should use: "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:/tool/vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
```

and I install sqlite3 for example:

```
PS D:\tool\vcpkg\vcpkg> vcpkg install sqlite3
Computing installation plan...
The following packages will be built and installed:
    sqlite3[core]:x86-windows -> 3.37.2#1
Detecting compiler hash for triplet x86-windows...
-- Automatically setting HTTP(S)_PROXY environment variables to 127.0.0.1:7890
Restored 1 packages from C:\Users\shen\AppData\Local\vcpkg\archives in 168.6 ms. Use --debug to see more details.
Starting package 1/1: sqlite3:x86-windows
Installing package sqlite3[core]:x86-windows...
Elapsed time for package sqlite3:x86-windows: 33.18 ms

Total elapsed time: 5.525 s

The package sqlite3 provides CMake targets:

    find_package(unofficial-sqlite3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE unofficial::sqlite3::sqlite3)
```

about the architecture
my computer is intel core i5-9300H, and it is x64, windows.
but to be on the safe side, i installed all windows architeture version,like this:

```
PS D:\tool\vcpkg\vcpkg> vcpkg list
jsoncpp:x86-windows                                1.9.5            jsoncpp is an implementation of a JSON reader an...
sqlite3:x64-windows                                3.37.2#1         SQLite is a software library that implements a s...
sqlite3:x64-windows-static                         3.37.2#1         SQLite is a software library that implements a s...
sqlite3:x86-windows                                3.37.2#1         SQLite is a software library that implements a s...
sqlite3:x86-windows-static                         3.37.2#1         SQLite is a software library that implements a s...
vcpkg-cmake-config:x64-windows                     2022-02-06
vcpkg-cmake:x64-windows                            2022-04-07
```

#### for C++ project, I tried by qtcreater(cmake), visual studio

##### 1,qtcreator with CMAKE

cmakelist.txt

```
SET(DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "D:/tool/vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
include("D:/tool/vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
if(DEFINED ENV{VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET} AND NOT DEFINED VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET)
    set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "$ENV{VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
endif()
...
find_package(unofficial-sqlite3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

and it told me:

```
D:\tool\vcpkg\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake:816: error: Could not find a package configuration file provided by "unofficial-sqlite3" with any of the following names: unofficial-sqlite3Config.cmake unofficial-sqlite3-config.cmake Add the installation prefix of "unofficial-sqlite3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "unofficial-sqlite3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "unofficial-sqlite3" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed. CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package)
:-1: error: [Makefile:249: cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
```

my full `CMakeLists.txt` is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

SET(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "D:/tool/vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
include("D:/tool/vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
if(DEFINED ENV{VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET} AND NOT DEFINED VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET)
    set(VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET "$ENV{VCPKG_DEFAULT_TRIPLET}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
endif()

project(untitled VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)

find_package(unofficial-sqlite3 CONFIG REQUIRED)


set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
        mainwindow.cpp
        mainwindow.h
        mainwindow.ui
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(untitled
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
# Define target properties for Android with Qt 6 as:
#    set_property(TARGET untitled APPEND PROPERTY QT_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR
#                 ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android)
# For more information, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qt-add-executable.html#target-creation
else()
    if(ANDROID)
        add_library(untitled SHARED
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
# Define properties for Android with Qt 5 after find_package() calls as:
#    set(ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/android")
    else()
        add_executable(untitled
            ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
        )
    endif()
endif()

target_link_libraries(untitled PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets sqlite3)

set_target_properties(untitled PROPERTIES
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_GUI_IDENTIFIER my.example.com
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_BUNDLE_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION}
    MACOSX_BUNDLE_SHORT_VERSION_STRING ${PROJECT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PROJECT_VERSION_MINOR}
)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(untitled)
endif()
```

most of above is generated by qtcreator

when I do those above, and stucked by these errors, I think, maybe it is caused by myqtcreator

so I tried with visual studio 2019

##### visual studio 2019

in cmakelist.txt i added those :

```
SET(DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "D:/tool/vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")
include("D:/tool/vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")

find_package(unofficial-sqlite3 CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

and it told me the same error:

```
严重性 代码  说明  项目  文件  行   禁止显示状态
错误      CMake Error at D:/tool/vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake:816 (_find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "unofficial-sqlite3" with any of the following names:

    unofficial-sqlite3Config.cmake
    unofficial-sqlite3-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "unofficial-sqlite3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or
  set "unofficial-sqlite3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above
  files.  If "unofficial-sqlite3" provides a separate development package or
  SDK, be sure it has been installed.       D:/tool/vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake    816
```

anyone can told me, how can I use the sqlite3 correctly?

> about `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN...` and 'DMAKE_TOOLCHAIN...`; any of them I have tried, and even both, but the result is the same.   QwQ

> about remove `include(.../vcpkg.cmake)`; i have saw a blog,and it says we need to add this line. but i still try to delete it,and reconfigure, and then, I got the same error

```
D:\tool\vcpkg\vcpkg\scripts\buildsystems\vcpkg.cmake:816: error: Could not find a package configuration file provided by "unofficial-sqlite3" with any of the following names: unofficial-sqlite3Config.cmake unofficial-sqlite3-config.cmake Add the installation prefix of "unofficial-sqlite3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "unofficial-sqlite3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "unofficial-sqlite3" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed. CMakeLists.txt:23 (find_package)
```

and the error is linked to vcpkg.cmake:

```
elseif("${z_vcpkg_find_package_lowercase_package_name}" STREQUAL "grpc" AND EXISTS "${_VCPKG_INSTALLED_DIR}/${VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET}/share/grpc")
        _find_package(gRPC ${z_vcpkg_find_package_ARGN})
    else()
        _find_package("${z_vcpkg_find_package_package_name}" ${z_vcpkg_find_package_ARGN})             <---- this line
    endif()
```

Comment: In `CMakeLists.txt` a toolchain file is assigned with `SET(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "D:/tool/vcpkg/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake")` command (note on the absence of `D` in the variable's name). This assignment should come **before** the `project()` call.

Comment: thank you for your reply :-)    I also tried the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN...` and these are before `project()` but these doesn't work, still cause the same error

Comment: First, remove `include(.../vcpkg.cmake)` from you `CMakeLists.txt`. Second, make sure you have installed sqlite for right architecture. Third, delete cache and reconfigure

Comment: thank you for your reply :-)   I removed it and installed all probably architecture,and reconfigure, but the error is still,,,,,

Answer (score 1):

Consider using:

```
find_package(SQLite3 REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(untitled PRIVATE SQLite::SQLite3)
```

inbuild CMake modules should work as expected using vcpkg.

Also make sure that `VCPKG_TARGET_TRIPLET` is not empty
Furthermore clean your cmake cache.